# Android system preferences reading

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I to read system settings (settings title, summary, value like Title: "Display brightness", summary "tune display brightness tuning", value = 230) 
from system preference tree (if it is exist)?

Or I have to create own preferences tree with own summary and titles and read system value in it with method `Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)?`

Answer (score 0):

The display names and descriptions of the settings, as used by the Settings application, are not part of the Android SDK.